# SQL Server、Azure SQL Databaseの認証に関して

Tags: database, sql-server, sql-azure

#### 現在の状況

自分が制作したアプリケーションが接続文字列を使用してローカルのデータベースとデータをやりとりできるようにしています。

#### 質問したいこと

アプリケーションをAzure App Serviceに公開してデータベースはAzure SQL Databaseに構築してデータベースと繋ごうと考えています。

その時Azure SQL Databaseのデータベースには接続文字列がないとログインできないのでしょうか？
自分以外の人がデータベースのデータをやりとりできるのかどうか心配です。

Answer (score 1):

SQL に限らず、まずは「認証」という仕組みについて理解する必要がありそうです。

基本的にはデータベースに対して作成したユーザー名 (とパスワード) を知る人以外は接続できません。

[認証 | Azure SQL Database と SQL Managed Instance のセキュリティ機能の概要](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/azure-sql/database/security-overview?view=azuresql#authentication)

> #### 認証
>
> 認証は、ユーザーが本人の主張どおりの人物であることを証明するプロセスです。
>
> ##### SQL 認証:
>
> SQL 認証とは、ユーザーがユーザー名とパスワードを使用して Azure SQL Database または Azure SQL Managed Instance に接続するときに、そのユーザーを認証することを指します。
> (中略)
> サーバー管理者は、追加の SQL ログインとユーザーを作成できます。これにより、ユーザーはユーザー名とパスワードを使用して接続できるようになります。

また、上記のユーザー認証だけでなく、大抵のデータベースでは「接続元」に対しても制限をかけることが出来るので、外部ネットワークからの直接的な接続を許可することは稀です。